# Does Firebird have "Group Commit"

Tags: firebird

As I understand it, this is where a background thread is responsible for writing transactions to disk in "careful write" order so that the user does not have to wait for the actual writing to disk to occur.

I have seen references to this (e.g. [here](http://borland.public.interbase.general.narkive.com/jRR7BtXK/group-commit-vs-forced-writes)) from a long time ago relating to interbase but I could not see it mentioned in relation to firebird anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on this thread and searching online it seems that firebird does not have GROUP COMMIT

Answer (score 1):

Using gfix utility you can set FORCED WRITES flag on or off for a database file. When turned on, the server will wait until actual disk write occur. When turned off the server will continue execution leaving to OS to decide when to write data to a disk. Performance gains are up to 3x but then there is a posibility that some data would be written in a wrong order if power failure occurs.

We strongly advice our customers toward using RAID controller with independent power source for a cache memory together with FORCED WRITES = ON.

Comment: Thanks, but is it still the case that every commit call has to wait for the data to be written to disk before returning to the caller? That's what it sounds like to me from what you have written. With 'group commit' the caller doesn't have to wait because instead it writes to a cache. This cache is is then written to disk by a separate thread in careful write order.

Comment: With FORCED WRITES OFF a commit call will return immediately. Data will stay in OS cache. OS will decide when to write them to disk. Also look at MaxUnflushedWrites and MaxUnflushedWriteTime parameters in firebird.conf

Comment: Thanks Andrej. There is no group commit in firebird then I think. With 'Group Commit' you get the speed advantages of FORCED WRITES OFF with FORCED WRITES actually turned on. The background thread does the actual careful writing to disk of a cache that can contain many transactions but in such a way that it is safe in the event of a crash, largely because because there are 2 separate copies of the Transaction inventory, one in memory and one on disk. It seems like a really cool feature and has been in interbase for 10 years or so.

Comment: -1 Because it doesn't answer the question and is actually misleading. According to some older Interbase documents, GROUP COMMIT is or used to be an in-between; a noticeable performance boost while not quite as risky as FORCED WRITES OFF. They are completely different things with different implications.

Comment: `GROUP COMMIT` is not something that is in Firebird, at all as far as I know.